# How can I get the directory count of a given directory in bash?

Tags: bash, count, directory

I am trying to use ls and grep to get the directory count, and store the value in a variable. Unfortunately I am getting this error: `./test.sh: line 3: -l: command not found`
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

assetid=ls -l /home/user/Desktop/folder | grep -c "^d"

echo $assetid
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I suggest: `assetid=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)`

Comment: @Cyrus That's just as bad as parsing `ls`; a directory name can contain a newline, so line count != file count.

Comment: @chepner: That is indeed an important point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will handle all cases:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo \; | wc -l
```

For each dir I print an empty newline... then count the newlines. Sadly `wc` does not work on null terminated strings, but we could remove all except zeros and count them:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

As to your script, you are getting the error, because you need to enclose to comment in `$( .. )` if you want to save it's output into a variable. Bash is space aware, I mean `a=1` is assigment, and `a = 1` is run program named `a` with arguments `=` and `1`. Bash interprets the line: `var=1 bash -c 'echo $var'` as first it sets `var=1` then runs the program `bash` with arguments `-c` and `'echo $var'`. Try this:

```
assetid=$(ls -l /home/user/Desktop/folder | grep -c "^d")
```

But don't parse `ls` output. `ls` is for human readable nice colored output, it's better to prefer using different utilities in batch/piped scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop an explicitly count each item resulting from a pattern.

```
count=0
for f in /home/user/Desktop/folder/*/; do
    count=$((count + 1))
done
```

If you need to include hidden directories as well, use

```
count=0
for f in /home/user/Desktop/folder/*/ /home/user/Desktop/folder/.*/; do
    count=$((count + 1))
done
```

If you aren't concerned about memory usage, fill an array and get the size of the resulting array

```
dirs=( /home/user/Desktop/folder/*/ )
count=${#dirs[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes SO formatting is off, but are you really trying to run the command: `assetid=ls -l /home/user/Desktop/folder | grep -c "^d"`?

If so, that is attempting to run the command `-l` with the environment variable `assetid` set to the string `ls`.  You probably intended to do

```
assetid=$( ls -l /home/user/Desktop/folder | grep -c "^d" )
```